# I got an error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&' token when overloading operator=

Tags: c++

I wrote things like that:

```
template <class T>
MyStack<T>::MyStack()
{
    STACK_SIZE=20;
    STACK_CURRENT=0;
    data=new T[STACK_SIZE];
}

template <class T>
MyStack<T>::MyStack(int thesize)
{
    STACK_SIZE=thesize;
    STACK_CURRENT=0;
    data=new T[STACK_SIZE];
}

template <class T>
MyStack<T>::MyStack(const MyStack& obj)
{
    STACK_SIZE=obj.STACK_SIZE;
    STACK_CURRENT=obj.STACK_CURRENT;
    data=new T[STACK_SIZE];
    for(int i=0; i<STACK_CURRENT; i++)
    {
        data[i]=obj.data[i];
    }
}

template <class T>
MyStack<T>::~MyStack()
{
//do nothing
}
//--------------------Get Error below this line-------------------------
template <class T> MyStack& MyStack<T>::operator=(const MyStack& obj)
//--------------------Get Error in this line---------------------------
{
STACK_SIZE=obj.STACK_SIZE;
STACK_CURRENT=obj.STACK_CURRENT;
data=new T*[STACK_SIZE];
for(int i=0; i<STACK_CURRENT; i++)
{
    data[i]=obj.data[i];
}
return *this;
}

template <class T>bool MyStack<T>::empty()
{
if(STACK_CURRENT==0) return true;
return false;
}

template <class T> T& MyStack<T>::top()
{
return data[STACK_CURRENT-1];
}

template <class T> void MyStack<T>::push(T& obj)
{
if(STACK_CURRENT>=STACK_SIZE-3)
{
    T* tempdata=new T[STACK_SIZE*2];
    for(int i=0; i<STACK_CURRENT; i++)
    {
        tempdata[i]=data[i];
    }
    delete[] data;
    data=new T[STACK_SIZE*2];
    for(int i=0; i<STACK_CURRENT; i++)
    {
        data[i]=tempdata[i];
    }
    STACK_SIZE+=STACK_SIZE;
}
data[STACK_CURRENT]=obj;
STACK_CURRENT++;
}

template <class T> void MyStack<T>::pop()
{
STACK_CURRENT--;
}

template <class T> int MyStack<T>::size()
{
return STACK_CURRENT;
}
```

My Header has declaration

```
template<class T> class MyStack
{
public:
MyStack();
MyStack(int);
MyStack(const MyStack&);
~MyStack();
MyStack& operator=(const MyStack&);
bool empty();
T& top();
void push(T&);
void pop();
int size();
private:
int STACK_SIZE;
int STACK_CURRENT;
T* data;
};
```

But I can't pass compiling, why? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using uppercase for variable names. Which line did you get the error at? Why not show the complete class definition? And you have a memory leak.

Comment: Could you provide a little bit more code to allow reproducing your error message? My guess would be, that you need to write `template<class T> MyStack<T>& ....`, but I can't verify it without more code.

Comment: Thank you! I've post entire code.

Comment: Is data a `T**`? It is maybe a stupid question but it seems that you only copy pointers to a new stack, not data.

Comment: Why this `data=new T*[STACK_SIZE]`?

Comment: This is a problem it should be T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-class member function definitions should also mention *type* argument:

```
template <class T> 
MyStack<T>& MyStack<T>::operator=(const MyStack<T>& obj)
//     ^^^ you forgot this                     ^^^ this too!
```

Just see these demos:

- http://www.ideone.com/BEMYn (error)
- http://www.ideone.com/f6Qzu (fixed)

Comment: Thanks! This really helps:) This is my first time writing a template, so a lot of stupid problems was made by me.:(

Answer (score 0):

Templated classes must be fully instantiated at compilation time, not linking time. So,

- Either you define all functions in the header,
- Either you use that class only in the compilation unit that defines the functions (so: MyStack.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Your erroneous line should be

```
template <class T> MyStack<T>& MyStack<T>::operator=(const MyStack& obj)
```

instead of

```
template <class T> MyStack& MyStack<T>::operator=(const MyStack& obj)
```